# logstash connection to database issue

Tags: postgresql, logstash

Using logstash, what I'm trying to do is dump all tagnames from a table in a database to an index. The problem I'm facing here is, the logstash works fine if specify the IP address as 127.0.0.1 for the postgresql connection.
But if I specify my actual IP or some other user's IP i'm not getting the connection and logstash eventually fails.

Here's the configuration :

```
input {
    jdbc {
        # Postgres jdbc connection string to our database, empris
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/empris"
        # The user we wish to execute our statement as
        jdbc_user => "postgres"
        #The password for the user 
        jdbc_password => ""
        # The path to our downloaded jdbc driver
        jdbc_driver_library => "/home/aravind/Desktop/postgresql-9.4-1206-jdbc4.jar"
        # The name of the driver class for Postgresql
        jdbc_driver_class => "org.postgresql.Driver"
        # our query
        statement => "SELECT distinct tagname from filemetadata"
    }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "192.168.16.238:9200"
        index => "arempris"
        document_type => "tags" 
    }
}
```

And if the `jdbc_connection_string` is `jdbc:postgresql://192.168.16.233:5432`,
logstash fails.

Would greatly appreciate your help making me understanding the cause of this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you ip you are mentioning is not accessible via logstash. Can you try to ping the ip and see if it is able to connect

Comment: Thanks for the response.Ya and there was a problem with my ip, when I pinged, it showed two different ips for my system. I had to correct some domain settings in my network configurations. And I had uncomment the line listen_address in postgresql.conf and change it to "*" because the port 5432 wasn't being accessed.